Eevee raytracing problem/not working correctly?
I usually use Eevee for a quick preview of what will the lighting look like, it works fine with Blender lights but I wanted to use emission materials in one of my renders. It didn't work at first with Eevee but after checking the settings and turning raytracing on the scene lit up.
However, when I turned the camera the other way, the object stopped emitting light?

I'm assuming that Eevee only uses raytracing on objects that are currently visible, is there a way to turn that off? Have it work more like Cycles and have all objects interact with the raytracing pipeline?
It also works with partially visible objects but the light is dimmer.

The letter word “screen“ in the screen tracing method tells you what you need to know. No, there’s probably no way to change this. You’ll just have to use cycles or a plane light.

"is there a way to turn that off?" No, you can minimize it somewhat with the Overscan option under Film but it is a fundamental property, not something you can "turn off". "Have it work more like Cycles and have all objects interact with the raytracing pipeline?" If you make EEVEE more like Cycles, you get Cycles, so why not just use Cycles instead?
